# Reverse the loop,write it backwards

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

The code was like this:

```
    for (int  i =0;i<[word length];i++)
```

I'd like to change it to:

```
 for (int  i =[word length]  ; i>0  ;i--)
```

but it doesn't work.

So can you help me,please

Comment: Please specify what is not working for you. Please add the code of the for loop

Comment: Objective-C or Swift ? Why did you tag with both ???

Comment: Change condition like this
for (int  i =[word length]-1  ; i>0  ;i--)

Comment: for (i, char) in word.characters.reversed().enumerated() {}

Answer (score 2):

```
 for (int  i =[word length]-1  ; i>=0  ;i--)
```

Answer (score -2):

And also put the length in a variable before the loop.

Comment: Ok Cool, just thinking on minor optimizations, like don´t re read the length on every turn in the loop